# Regex return in result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need get a results of a expression, but I don't want the expression returned in the results.

Example:

I want get all a-z preceded by THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION...

I want get:

```
thisismyfirstvalue, thisismysecondvalue, thisismythirdvalue, thisismyfourvalue
```

from:

```
thisismyfirstvalueTHISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITIONhellowworld
thisismysecondvalueTHISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITIONhellowworld
thisismythirdvalueTHISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITIONhellowworld
thisismyfourvalueTHISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITIONhellowworld
```

How I can do it?

I've tried the following but they aren't right:

```
[a-z]*(THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION)
[a-z]*(?=THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION)
[a-z]*(=?THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION)
```

Remember: I don't want the condition returned in the results.

Comment: PHP... but i go user preg_match i use '//' sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(.*?)THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION/
```

Comment: He specifically said that he wanted "all a-z", the dot matches anything.

Answer (score 1):

`^([a-zA-Z]*?)(?=THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION)`, remove the "A-Z" if you actually want case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP and `preg_*` functions, this is a job for `preg_replace()` if I understand what you're attempting. If I get your intent, you are not looking to pass on matching if `THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION` is present, but rather not return it from the string:

```
echo preg_replace("/^([a-z]*)(THISCANTRETURNJUSTCONDITION)(.*)$/", '$1', $input_string);
//-----------------(Group1)
//--------------------------(Group2 boundary------------)
//-------------------------------------------------------(Group 3 after boundary)
```

The pattern is replaced by only the contents of Group1 `([a-z]*)` with `$1`.